# How to avoid HTML Entities being converted to html form CAST(@ContentXml AS XML) in SQL Server

Tags: c#, html, sql-server, xml

I have a following XML `DECLARE @xml XML = CAST(@ContentXml AS XML)` . Here I am sending following XM

```
<content>
    <data>0</data>
    <cont>"&lt;b&gt;hello&lt;&#x2F;b&gt;"</cont>
    <data>0</data>
    <cont>"&lt;b&gt;hello&lt;&#x2F;b&gt;"</cont>
</content>
```

And I have following SQL Query

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    ContentID INT,
    Content NVARCHAR(500)
)

INSERT INTO @TempTable
    SELECT
    N.value('(./id/text())[1]', 'INT') AS ContentID
    ,N.value('(./cont/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(500)') AS Content
    FROM @xml.nodes('/content/data') AS T(N)
```

This Query return me following result.

```
0 <b>hello</b>
0 <b>hello</b>
```

How can I prevent the HTML Entities being converted to equivalent HTML code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I got this correctly: You want to get the internal part *as-is*?

One pragmatic approach was, to place the string you get into a new `SELECT ... FOR XML PATH` sub-select like here:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<content>
    <data>0</data>
    <cont>"&lt;b&gt;hello&lt;&#x2F;b&gt;"</cont>
    <data>0</data>
    <cont>"&lt;b&gt;hello&lt;&#x2F;b&gt;"</cont>
</content>';

SELECT
    N.value('(../data/text())[1]', 'INT') AS ContentID
    ,N.value('(../cont/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(500)')  AS Content
    ,(SELECT N.value('(../cont/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(500)') FOR XML PATH('')) AS ContentEscaped
    FROM @xml.nodes('/content/data') AS T(N);
```

This will re-encode your entities...

```
ContentID   Content  ContentEscaped

0   "<b>hello</b>"  "&lt;b&gt;hello&lt;/b&gt;"
0   "<b>hello</b>"  "&lt;b&gt;hello&lt;/b&gt;"
```

#### Some explanation

It is a wrong idea to think of the part **within** XML as an embedded string you take out. The actual string is `"<b>hello</b>"`. XML will not support to read this untranslated. You might do this on string level (with `SUBSTRING`).

Another approach was a `REPLACE` in advance, to encode the `&` sign. This will lead to the needed result too (`&amp;lt;` is taken as `&lt;`):

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
REPLACE(
N'<content>
    <data>0</data>
    <cont>"&lt;b&gt;hello&lt;&#x2F;b&gt;"</cont>
    <data>0</data>
    <cont>"&lt;b&gt;hello&lt;&#x2F;b&gt;"</cont>
</content>','&','&amp;');

SELECT
    N.value('(../data/text())[1]', 'INT') AS ContentID
    ,N.value('(../cont/text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')  AS Content
    FROM @xml.nodes('/content/data') AS T(N)
```